# Beautifulsoup get both text and value from option tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hello i have the following html that i am getting from a beautifulsoup request

```
<select class="select" name="Type">
   <option value="1">Test A</option>
   <option value="2">Test B</option>
   <option value="3">Test C</option>
   <option value="4">Test D</option>
</select>
```

I have the following code to get me this and i can loop through it and only print out the values, but i can't print out the corresponding text for it. If i want to get the text, i would need to loop it adding the stripped_strings, but then i can only get the text, not the corresponding value. Is there a way to get both

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
list_a = soup.find('select', {'name':'Type'})

# This will get me only the text
for i in list_a.stripped_strings:
    print(i)

# This will get me only the values
list = list_a.find_all('option')
for x in list:
    val = x.get('value')
    print(str(val))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you what you need:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<select class="select" name="Type">
   <option value="1">Test A</option>
   <option value="2">Test B</option>
   <option value="3">Test C</option>
   <option value="4">Test D</option>
</select>
'''

soup = bs(html)
options = soup.select_one('select[name="Type"]').select('option')
for op in options:
    print(op.get_text(), '|', op.get('value'))
```

Result in terminal:

```
Test A | 1
Test B | 2
Test C | 3
Test D | 4
```

BeautifulSoup docs can be found here: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html